# If I delete a repository, will RawGit still have it cached?

Tags: github

I have a repository on GitHub that I no longer want developers to use in favor of a new one. I am using RawGit to serve it to my websites. If I were to remove that repository, is it still cached on Rawgit? I want it still to be used by older sites of mine until they are migrated over.

I'm using the production url for RawGit.

Comment: Probably, but why not just add a notice that the repo is deprecated, and direct them to here they should go?

Comment: Good idea. I can delete the content, add a note in the README.md, and leave the releases there.